# How to delete file/folder with specific names only if there is another file with certain extension in that folder with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, automation, windows-11

As a developer, I have many `bin` and `obj` folders that I would like to cleanup to reclaim some space. I can use this script:

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

However, to be safe, I only want to delete them if in the folder that contains `bin` or `obj` folder, there is a file with `.csproj` or `.sln` extension. Is it possible?

Comment: you can add a `| where` before the foreach to limit the get-childitem even further. Or just search for the extensions alone, and for all that are found, check if they are in a bin or obj folder.

Comment: @LPChip I checked the [`Where` syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2), unfortunately I still cannot understand how to do that. I wrote a .NET tool to do that, but you can add your PowerShell answer too, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am too bad at PowerShell so I wrote a CLI tool to do the task. You can check this out [NetCleaner on GitHub](https://github.com/datvm/NetCleaner).

You need [.NET 6.0 or above](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

```
dotnet tool install -g NetCleaner

# List (run in WhatIf mode)
netclean -s
```

Actually delete the files/folders:

```
netclean -s -d
```